# programmaticaly extract the shipping service name

Tags: 7, commerce

Through following code in a custom sub module for commerce_cybersource_sawm I am able to pass shipping information to merchant like name, address, country

```
$shipping_address = $order_wrapper->commerce_customer_shipping->commerce_customer_address->value();
 if (!empty($shipping_address['first_name'])) {
    $form['ship_to_forename'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $shipping_address['first_name'],
  );
}
```

I want to know how can we extract the shipping service name. Since I have Free Shipping and Standard Shipping which I want to pass to the merchant.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer, just found a code sample from @googletorp on the link below. Just modified that and got the result.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1555994#comment-5963680

```
    foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
    if ($line_item_wrapper->type->value() == 'shipping' ){
    $form['merchant_defined_data6'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $line_item_wrapper->commerce_shipping_service->value(),
  );

  break;
  }
}
```